# Генерация кода по заданной структуре JSON API

Tags: php, java, android, suitecrm

Я не уверен, отностися ли это полностью к SuiteCRM или к JSON API. Вероятно, это что-то посередине.

Есть ресурс с название `Lead`, чья структура целиком доступна, если выполнить такой запрос:

```
GET {{crm_base_url}}/api/v8/modules/Leads/meta/attributes
```

Это дает такой ответ:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "Leads": {
            "attributes": {
                "id": {
                    "name": "id",
                    "vname": "LBL_ID",
                    "type": "id",
                    "required": true,
                    "reportable": true,
                    "comment": "Unique identifier",
                    "inline_edit": false
                },
                "first_name": {
                    "name": "first_name",
                    "vname": "LBL_FIRST_NAME",
                    "type": "varchar",
                    "len": "100",
                    "unified_search": true,
                    "full_text_search": {
                        "boost": 3
                    },
                    "comment": "First name of the contact",
                    "merge_filter": "selected"
                },
                ...
```

Я хочу использовать одну из JSON API библиотек. Допустим, [Java реализацию](http://jsonapi.org/implementations/#client-libraries-java). Тогда я должен написать такой код:

```
@JsonApiResource(type = "Leads")
public class Lead {

    @JsonApiId
    private UUID id;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;
    ...
```

Как я могу избежать ручной работы и сгенерировать код таких классов автоматически?

Неважно какой язык программирования использовать, в результате должен получится класс с полями.

Answer (score 0):

Немного погуглив (так как тема явно не нова). Нашел пару решений.
https://github.com/astav/JsonToJava:

Особенности

Может генерировать классы для произвольно сложной иерархии (рекурсивно)
Может читать ваши существующие классы Java и, если он может десериализоваться в этих структурах, сделает это
Будет запрашивать ввод пользователя, если существуют двусмысленные случаи

https://timboudreau.com/blog/json/read - онлайн инструмент

https://github.com/inder123/json2java- как и все вышеперечисленное, преобразует json в java объекты.

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foobnix/android-universal-utils/master/json/generator.html - еще один онлайн инструмент.

Comment: Все правильно, тема не нова, но есть ньюанс - JSON API. Это достаточно новый подход и MIME тип здесь не `application/json`, а `application/vnd.api+json`, что делает обычный подход не совсем подходящим

Comment: Вообще, главная проблема при  данном подходе в том, что json не предполагает сохранение типов. Вам по любому придется править код класса прошедший через декодер, либо писать свой собственный.

Comment: А можно как-то по схеме генерировать. Например в предке SuiteCRM'а - SugarCRM была возможность генерировать по wsdl: https://www.slideshare.net/amusarra/how-tobuildjavaclientforsugarcrm-enit10 ?

Comment: на сколько я знаю, wsd - это xml. Мне кажется, что если вы готовы писать схемы, то уже проще написать сам класс.